# Android Development: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, json, api, android-asynctask, futuretask

I have been trying to learn a bit about Android Development. After a couple of "Hello World" and simple App, i decided i would like to make something i could actually use: a simple Weather App. I found a nice [tutorial](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/build-weather-app-json-http-android.html), so i was following that.

Instead of just copy and pasting it, i have been reading through it, trying to understand it and adapting it to my own project.

When i try to run it on my phone i get this Error on the Android Monitor:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.anatis.ueder, PID: 29363
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
      at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
      at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
      at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
      at com.anatis.ueder.JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(JSONWeatherParser.java:17)
      at com.anatis.ueder.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:63)
      at com.anatis.ueder.MainActivity$JSONWeatherTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:55)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

ai, ai, ai... i have no idea what this means!
I have read through other thread about this AsyncTask #1, but i couldn't figure out what the problem was.
I also don't know where the problem is, so i don't know what code i should post here.
This id the doInBackground()

```
@Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {
        Weather weather = new Weather();
        String data = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0]));

        try {
            weather = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

            // Let's retrieve the icon
            weather.iconData = ( (new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;
    }
```

and here is the getWeather() from the JSONWeatherParser.java

```
public static Weather getWeather(String data) throws JSONException {
    Weather weather = new Weather();

    // We create out JSONObject from the data
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(data);

    // We start extracting the info
    Location loc = new Location();

    JSONObject coordObj = getObject("coord", jObj);
    loc.setLatitude(getFloat("lat", coordObj));
    loc.setLongitude(getFloat("lon", coordObj));

    JSONObject sysObj = getObject("sys", jObj);
    loc.setCountry(getString("country", sysObj));
    loc.setSunrise(getInt("sunrise", sysObj));
    loc.setSunset(getInt("sunset", sysObj));
    loc.setCity(getString("name", jObj));
    weather.location = loc;

    // We get weather info (This is an array)
    JSONArray jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("weather");

    // We use only the first value
    JSONObject JSONWeather = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
    weather.currentCondition.setWeatherId(getInt("id", JSONWeather));
    weather.currentCondition.setDescr(getString("description", JSONWeather));
    weather.currentCondition.setCondition(getString("main", JSONWeather));
    weather.currentCondition.setIcon(getString("icon", JSONWeather));

    JSONObject mainObj = getObject("main", jObj);
    weather.currentCondition.setHumidity(getInt("humidity", mainObj));
    weather.currentCondition.setPressure(getInt("pressure", mainObj));
    weather.temperature.setMaxTemp(getFloat("temp_max", mainObj));
    weather.temperature.setMinTemp(getFloat("temp_min", mainObj));
    weather.temperature.setTemp(getFloat("temp", mainObj));

    // Wind
    JSONObject wObj = getObject("wind", jObj);
    weather.wind.setSpeed(getFloat("speed", wObj));
    weather.wind.setDeg(getFloat("deg", wObj));

    // Clouds
    JSONObject cObj = getObject("clouds", jObj);
    weather.clouds.setPerc(getInt("all", cObj));

    // We download the icon to show


    return weather;
}
```

Any ideas of what is going on and how i could fix it?

Please, if you need to see any other code let me know.

I really appreciate all help i can get ( i was hoping to get this to work before Christmas, so i could give the app to my father as Christmas Present...    ;)   )

Thank you!!!

Comment: your error is java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference so please update your code

Comment: what is JSONWeatherParser.java:17 ???

Comment: Aashvi, how should i update the code? Stefan, the JSONWeatherParser.java is a class i copied from the tutorial. ou can see it [here](https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/Swa-app/blob/master/WeatherApp/src/com/survivingwithandroid/weatherapp/JSONWeatherParser.java), i just updated then the package name to fit my project

Comment: You should try to put a log over the string who's length you are trying the fetch and see what it is returning.. through log cat

Comment: man your code is incomplete, where are fetching the length of string ?

Comment: :/ i don't know. I was just following the tutorial. i have almost no idea at all what all the code means...    :(

Comment: You need to post your `JSONWeatherParser.getWeather` source

Comment: tato.rodrigo, i updated the question, i added the getWeather() from the JSONWeatherParser.